# Commit from Eclipse's project explorer via egit with keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, commit, egit

In `Preferences > General > Keys > Commit` the `binding` shortcut is set to `⌘#`. `When` is set to  `In Windows`.

When executing the shortcut from the editor window, the currently edited file is the only preselected file (very sensible in my opinion).

Executing the short cut from the project explorer does nothing though. It should execute the same action as when I'm using the context menu, meaning it should preselect all files under the currently highlighted resource.

Is this a configuration issue or should a file a feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure `Git` is checked within the `Command Groups Availability` tab of the Window > Customize Perspective menu.

Comment: Wow. I'll be honest, I never looked into that dialog, didn't even know that it was there. Thanks a lot.